# How can I filter twice the information in a table with Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript

I have a table of athletes that I want to filter by country and by gender. I am using two select but they both work separately. For example, if I want to see the athletes from Argentina, the select can filter but if I want to see the male athletes from Argentina, it shows the male athletes from all the countries that participated. I would like how I can integrate both filters.

this is main.js

```
import { getByCountry, getByGender,} from "./data.js";
import data from "./data/athletes/athletes.js";

const athletesData = data.athletes;


//Obteniendo elementos del DOM
const firstTable = document.getElementById("tbAthletes");
const athletesTableLink = document.getElementById("atlethesLink");
const informationDisplay = document.getElementById("firstPage");
const athletesTableDisplay = document.getElementById("secondPage");
const atletheCount = document.getElementById("atletheCount");
const countriesSelect = document.getElementById("selectCountries");
const genderSelect = document.getElementById("selectGender");

function paintTable(data) {
  let athletesInformation = ``;

  for (const item of data) {
    athletesInformation += `
    <tr>
      <td>${item.name}</td>
      <td>${item.gender}</td>
      <td>${item.height}</td>
      <td>${item.weight}</td>
      <td>${item.sport}</td>
      <td>${item.team}</td>
      <td>${item.noc}</td>
      <td>${item.age}</td>
      <td>${item.event}</td>
      <td>${item.medal}</td>
    </tr>
  `;
  }

  firstTable.innerHTML = athletesInformation;
  atletheCount.innerHTML = data.length;
}

//Pintar países en el select

function paintCountries(data) {
  let dataTeam = data.map((ele) => ele.team);
  let sortData = Array.from(new Set(dataTeam.sort()));
  let countriesSelectOption = ``;
  for (const item of sortData) {
    countriesSelectOption += `
        <option class="option-country" value="${item}">${item}</option>

    `;
  }

  countriesSelect.innerHTML = countriesSelectOption;
}

//Pintar géneros en el select

function paintGender(data) {
  let dataGender = data.map((ele) => ele.gender);
  let setDataGender = Array.from(new Set(dataGender));
  let gendersSelectOption = ``;

  for (const item of setDataGender) {
    gendersSelectOption += `
    
        <option class="option-gender" value="${item}">${item}</option>
    `;
  }

  genderSelect.innerHTML = gendersSelectOption;
}

//Eventos del DOM
//Quita la seccion de información y muestra la página con los filtros y la tabla de atletas
athletesTableLink.addEventListener("click", () => {
  paintTable(athletesData);
  paintCountries(athletesData);
  paintGender(athletesData);
  informationDisplay.style.display = "none";
  athletesTableDisplay.style.display = "block";
});
 
countriesSelect.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  const country = e.target.value;
  const dataFilteredByCountry = getByCountry(athletesData, country);
  paintTable(dataFilteredByCountry,);

});


genderSelect.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  const gender = e.target.value;
  const dataFilteredByGender = getByGender(athletesData, gender);
  paintTable(dataFilteredByGender);
});
```

Here I use the filter method

```
export const getByCountry = (data, country) => {
  const countryFilterData = data.filter(item => item.team === country);
  return countryFilterData;
};

export const getByGender = (data,gender) => {
  const genderFilterData = data.filter(item => item.gender === gender);
  return genderFilterData;
};
```

This is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scales=1.0">
    <title>Data Lovers</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="icon" href="./Imagenes para DataLovers/olimpicos - copia.ico">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <header> 
          <h1>
            Juegos Olimpicos
          </h1>
        </header>
      <section class="principal">
        <div class="articles">
          <article class="menu">
            <a href="#" class="pointer" id="menuLink">Menu</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#" class="pointer" id="atlethesLink">Atletas participantes</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="pointer" id="sportsLink">Deportes participantes</a></li>
            </ul>
              </article>
            <article class="location">
              <p>Localización:</p>
              <p>Brasil - Rio de Janeriro</p>
            </article>
        </div>
        <main class="information" id="firstPage">
          <p>Los Juegos Olímpicos de Río de Janeiro 2016, oficialmente conocidos como los Juegos de la XXXI Olimpiada, 
          o más comúnmente como Río 2016, fue un evento multideportivo internacional, celebrado en la ciudad de 
          Río de Janeiro, Brasil, entre el 5 y el 21 de agosto de 2016.
          </p>
          <p>
          La mascota olímpica Vinicius representa la fauna brasileña, es un animal amarillo de brazos azules con 
          rasgos de mamíferos como gatos y monos. 
          </p>
          <p>
          Para más información haz <a href="https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juegos_Ol%C3%ADmpicos_de_R%C3%ADo_de_Janeiro_2016" target="_blank">click aquí</a>.
          </p>
        </main>
        <main class="atlethes" id="secondPage">
          <select id="selectCountries" style="width:20%">  
            <option class="option-country" value="País">--País--</option>
          </select>
          <select id="selectGender" style="width:20%">
            <option class="option-gender" value="Género">--Género--</option>
          </select>
          <div>
            <p>Total atletas <span id="atletheCount"></span></p>
          </div>
        <table id="tableAthletes">
          <thead id="thAthletes">
            <tr>
              <th id="name">Nombre</th>
              <th id="gener">Genero</th>
              <th id="heigth">Altura(cm)</th>
              <th id="weigth">Peso(Kg)</th>
              <th id="sport">Deporte</th>
              <th id="country">País</th>
              <th id="noc">COI</th>
              <th id="age">Edad</th>
              <th id="eventSport">Evento Deportivo</th>
              <th id="medal">Medallas</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="tbAthletes">
          </tbody>
        </table>
        </main>
        <main class="participatingCountries" id="thirdPage">
          <p>COmo</p>
        </main>
        <main class="sports" id="fourthPage">
          <p>Estas?</p>
        </main>
      </section>
      <footer class="foot">
        <p>Elaborado por: Camila Cortes y Nataly Escobar. Todos los derechos reservados.</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get the information of the athletes from a data file that contains an array with objects inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call both your filter functions one after the other and you will get only items that pass both filters. However if you do this, you would have to add another option for "All countries" and another option for "All genders", otherwise you wont be able to filter just by country or just by gender once you filter by both.

In `paintCountries` change this line

```
let countriesSelectOption = `<option class="option-gender" value="_all">All countries</option>`;
```

In `paintGender` change this line

```
let gendersSelectOption = `<option class="option-gender" value="_all">All genders</option>`;
```

Add a function that will conditionally call both filtering functions one after the other and return the filtered data listeners

```
function filterData(data, country, gender) {
  if (country && country !== "_all") {
    data = getByCountry(data, country);
  }
  if (gender && gender !== "_all") {
    data = getByGender(data, gender);
  }
  return data
}
```

Update your change event listeners to use this new filtering function instead

```
let selectedCountry = undefined;
countriesSelect.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  selectedCountry = e.target.value;
  paintTable(filterData(athletesData, selectedCountry, selectedGender));
});

let selectedGender = undefined;
genderSelect.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  selectedGender = e.target.value;
  paintTable(filterData(athletesData, selectedCountry, selectedGender));
});
```

Here is your original code with these edited in (without the link click handler and with less data in the table). Run the code snippet to see how it works.

```js
const athletesData = [
  { team: "Spain", gender: "Gender 1" },
  { team: "Spain", gender: "Gender 2" },
  { team: "Spain", gender: "Gender 3" },
  { team: "Mexico", gender: "Gender 1" },
  { team: "Mexico", gender: "Gender 2" },
  { team: "Mexico", gender: "Gender 3" },
  { team: "United States", gender: "Gender 1" },
  { team: "United States", gender: "Gender 2" },
  { team: "United States", gender: "Gender 3" }
];

//Obteniendo elementos del DOM
const firstTable = document.getElementById("tbAthletes");
const atletheCount = document.getElementById("atletheCount");
const countriesSelect = document.getElementById("selectCountries");
const genderSelect = document.getElementById("selectGender");

function paintTable(data) {
  let athletesInformation = ``;

  for (const item of data) {
    athletesInformation += `
      <tr>
        <td>${item.gender}</td>
        <td>${item.team}</td>
      </tr>
    `;
  }

  firstTable.innerHTML = athletesInformation;
  atletheCount.innerHTML = data.length;
}

//Pintar países en el select

function paintCountries(data) {
  let dataTeam = data.map((ele) => ele.team);
  let sortData = Array.from(new Set(dataTeam.sort()));
  let countriesSelectOption = `<option class="option-gender" value="_all">All countries</option>`;
  for (const item of sortData) {
    countriesSelectOption += `
        <option class="option-country" value="${item}">${item}</option>
    `;
  }

  countriesSelect.innerHTML = countriesSelectOption;
}

//Pintar géneros en el select

function paintGender(data) {
  let dataGender = data.map((ele) => ele.gender);
  let setDataGender = Array.from(new Set(dataGender));
  let gendersSelectOption = `<option class="option-gender" value="_all">All genders</option>`;

  for (const item of setDataGender) {
    gendersSelectOption += `    
        <option class="option-gender" value="${item}">${item}</option>
    `;
  }

  genderSelect.innerHTML = gendersSelectOption;
}

//Eventos del DOM
 
let selectedCountry = undefined;
countriesSelect.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  selectedCountry = e.target.value;
  paintTable(filterData(athletesData, selectedCountry, selectedGender));
});

let selectedGender = undefined;
genderSelect.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  selectedGender = e.target.value;
  paintTable(filterData(athletesData, selectedCountry, selectedGender));
});

function filterData(data, country, gender) {
  if (country && country !== "_all") {
    data = getByCountry(data, country);
  }
  if (gender && gender !== "_all") {
    data = getByGender(data, gender);
  }
  return data
}

const getByCountry = (data, country) => {
  const countryFilterData = data.filter(item => item.team === country);
  return countryFilterData;
};

const getByGender = (data,gender) => {
  const genderFilterData = data.filter(item => item.gender === gender);
  return genderFilterData;
};

paintCountries(athletesData)
paintGender(athletesData)
paintTable(athletesData)
```

```html
<main class="atlethes" id="secondPage">
  <select id="selectCountries" style="width:20%">  
    <option class="option-country" value="País">--País--</option>
  </select>
  <select id="selectGender" style="width:20%">
    <option class="option-gender" value="Género">--Género--</option>
  </select>
  <div>
    <p>Total atletas <span id="atletheCount"></span></p>
  </div>
  <table id="tableAthletes">
    <thead id="thAthletes">
      <tr>
        <th id="gener">Genero</th>
        <th id="country">País</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbAthletes">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</main>
```